# Keys for different controllers in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, upload, controller

I have a user registration page, and I am creating a user account. Instead of storing image as bytes, i am storing it on the server. So, in my controller, I have two different actions, Create() and UploadImage() in the Register Controller. I am not getting the idea about how is the key assigned for image to let the database know that it should pull a particular image from the server for a particular account? I am not getting any idea on how the key is stored for the image?

Create Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "studentId,firstName,middleName,lastName,dateOfBirth,country,emailAddress,userName,userPassword,confirmPassword,university")] Student student)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
                var saltedPassword = student.userPassword + salt;
                var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(saltedPassword);
                student.userPassword = hashedPassword;
                student.confirmPassword = hashedPassword;
                student.salt = salt;
                db.Students.Add(student);   
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("UploadImage");
            }

            return View(student);
        }
```

Upload Image action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
        {
            string path = @"~/Content/profileImage";

            if (photo != null)
                photo.SaveAs(path + photo.FileName);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

My model for both is same i.e. all other variables and the image is on the same model.:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int studentId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [Display(Name="First Name*")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
        public string middleName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name*")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }

         [FileSize(10240)]
        [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How can i link two different controller for 1 same id?

Answer (score 0):

In your image model you need to specify the key to be used in the database. For example:

```
public class Image {

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Then in your student class you can declare the following:

```
public class Student {

    Image image { get; set; }

}
```

In order to create a controller action for this it would look something like

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult(int id) 
    {
        //Method to query image models by id

    return View(model);

}
```

Comment: i have them on the same model, don't have a different model for the image.

Comment: Without having a different model for the image class there is no way to have a separate key for the image in the database. Only one primary key. I would suggest you create a separate class and create a relationship between the image and the current class if you need an image id as such. Hope I am understanding you correctly

Comment: so i cannot establish a link if they are in the same model? By the way in am storing the images on the server, not on database as bytes.

Comment: Aww I see. I would strongly recommend you store an image entity in the database with a primary key and a string referencing the stored path. This way you have flexibility and scalability of you entities. Let me know if I need to update my answer

Comment: you mean an public bytes[] >?